# Type aliasing in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, states

I don't actually know what to call this question. The title presented was the best I could come up with.

We are currently working with functional programming in Scala in school, and every so often there are a few instances where something just doesn't make sense in the way of things I am used to... A particular example is this:

```
type Rand[+A] = RNG => (A, RNG)

val int: Rand[Int] = _.nextInt

def unit[A](a: A): Rand[A] =
   rng => (a, rng)
```

We are dealing with states here, trying to combat the repetition of having to transfer a new state to each function every time we are generating new random numbers using our RNG trait.

My question is this:

The lambda function expression defines the predicate "`rng =>`" to be used as the place holder for our state. Normally what this predicate defines is clear such as with `List.map(x => x)` where x is each element of the list. But it is not clear to me what `rng` is here.

EDIT: I guess some people didn't understand the question so I will give some further examples here to clarify...

I'm not asking what Rand[A] is representing. I am asking what the received argument `rng =>` is supposed to be interpreted as... For example

```
def map[A,B](l: List[A])(f: A => B): List[B] = ...
val l = List(1,2,3,4,5)
// l.map(x => x+1) -> List(2,3,4,5,6)
```

In the above map example, it is *very* easy to conceptually understand that the received argument `x =>` given by the function argument `f` is to be interpreted as each individual element of the list `l`.

I am specifically looking for such a conceptual connection with `rng =>` in `unit`.

Comment: `rng` is just another `x` or `_`. It is a received argument. In this case it is some arg/parameter of type `RNG`. Type `Rand` is a function that receives an `RNG` and produces a tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I'll have a go at it.

```
def unit[A](a: A): Rand[A] = rng => (a, rng)
```

Here `unit` takes one argument and builds half of a tuple. It returns the means to build the completed tuple.

```
val uHalf = unit('q')  // this is the "a" parameter
```

Now, because of the definition of type `Rand` (and `uHalf` is of type `Rand`) the other half of the tuple can only be of type `RNG`, which isn't defined in your code example. But let's say you have a `blob` of type `RNG` handy.

```
val tup = uHalf(blob)  // this is the "rng" parameter
```

Now you have the tuple `('q', blob)`.

You're right, in the example `List(3,2,1).map(x => ...`, `x` is the stand-in for values supplied from the `List`. In the case of `Rand`, `rng` is the stand-in for a value (of type `RNG`) to be supplied sometime/somewhere later in the code.

Comment: This helped me a ton in understanding it. I didn't realize it was to be used in a curried way (half-a-Rand as you put it). Thanks man! You really hit the nail on the head.